# Share the same dimension to multiple cubes or tabular models

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, tabular, ssas-tabular

What is the best practice (and why you consider this as the best) for using of the same dimension in multiple data models (either multid or tabular).

In the case of necessity to have the same dimension in multiple models ("region", "trade net", "product" whatever) should I either use **single** database view as a datasource for the appropriate dimensions of each data model or create multiple database views based on the same dimension table and use "personal" database view as a source for the dimension of each certain data model?

Comment: Based on this very limited explanation, there is no reason to use multiple views. There is in fact no reason to use a view. Just use a table.  I don't know that you mean by 'personal' database view

Comment: Under "personal" database view I mean that each certain data model uses it's own copy of appropriate dimension view.. To use views as data sources for data models or not to use, I think there is no question. It's absolutely reasonable best practice to use exactly views as a data sources for data models instead of tables themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are worried about tracking usage by SSAS model, I can't think of a good reason to duplicate the view for each tabular model. If it truly is a shared dimension, it would be easier to have one view. If changes are made to the view, they would then be reflected in all tabular models.

I agree on using views in general to feed a tabular model. They provide a level of abstraction so you can limit columns, add calculations, and control what goes into the tabular model with no surprises from new columns being added.